# Comparar campo tipo SqlTimeStamp

Tags: delphi

estou com uma dúvida aqui...
Tenho um campo no banco SQL Server do tipo DateTime que pode ser nulo.
No Delphi, dentro do MemTable (ou ClientDataSet... seria a mesma coisa nesse meu caso), o campo foi criado como SQLTimeStamp Field.
Eu quero ver se esse campo possui uma data ou está nulo, mas não cheguei a uma comparação correta sem dar erro de compilação dizendo que os tipos são diferentes.
Segue o código:

```
if fDm.fdmEmail.FieldByName('esr_ultimo').AsSQLTimeStamp > 0 then // Aqui dá erro na compilação
begin
  // Formatar o campo...
  edtUltimo.Text := SQLTimeStampToStr('dd/mm/yyyy', fDm.fdmEmail.FieldByName('esr_ultimo').AsSQLTimeStamp);
end;
```

Já tentei "<> NULL", "<> 'NULL'", e várias outras...
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Tente usar o `.AsDateTime` ao inves de `.AsSQLTimeStamp`, e diga se o resultado foi positivo.

Comment: Victor, deu certo. Ao formatar a data para o campo edit eu também utilizei "AsDateTime" e a função "FormatDateTime" para formatá-la corretamente. Obrigado!

Comment: Poderia transformar o comentário em resposta?

Comment: Perdão, sou novo por aqui... com faço isso?

Comment: Também não sei direito como. mas acredito que o autor da pergunta tenha essa opção, dá uma olhada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2333/por-que-muitas-pessoas-respondem-nos-coment%C3%A1rios-em-vez-de-criar-uma-resposta/2334#2334

Comment: Para mi não aparece nada que me permita isso. Acho que preciso ter mais pontuações para eu poder transformar comentários em respostas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar o `.AsDateTime` ao inves de `.AsSQLTimeStamp`, e diga se o resultado foi positivo.

Comment: O destaque de citação não se aplica para este caso. Você não precisa aplicar destaque de citação a uma resposta, apenas porque era um comentário virou respota.

Comment: Bacana, obrigado pela informação.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a propriedade IsNull, ficaria assim:

```
fDm.fdmEmail.FieldByName('esr_ultimo').IsNull;
```

Esta propriedade retorna true/false.